# Hybrid Pagination (Client + Server) side pagination using Backbone Backgrid

Tags: backbone.js, pagination, marionette

I have a Marionette application which is using Backgrid control to fetch records from a backend API.

My requirement :

1. While Bootstrapping fetch 100 records and split them into 5 pages of 20 each.
2. For the first 5 pages implement Client side pagination i.e no call to backend.
3. To load the next 100 records on the 6th page make a backend call to fetch the records.

Can this be achieved using the "infinite" mode setting in backgrid paginator?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Why not use server mode and only fetch the first page? Any subsequent page being fetched on demand.

Comment: That would be the ideal solution. But i'm exploring if something like this can be implemented without too much hassle.

Comment: I wanted to do infinite scroll using backbone paginator and I finally gave up on changing the collection behavior as it's not meant to be change. I rolled my own collection inspired by the paginator one.